# How can I add a 2D image heatmap on a 3D surface from a specific perspective?

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, image, texture-painting, 2d

How can I add a 2D image heatmap on a 3D surface from a specific perspective?

What I did now is that I roughly looked where the heatmap is drawn on the image (left) and texture paint it on the 3d model (right) by hand. That is a way to do it but not really exact and a lot of guess work.

What I want to know is if there is a way to exactly draw/map the 2D Image of the heatmap (left) on the 3d model(right)?

[image: Visuals: 2d heatmap & 3d model]

Maybe by aligning the exact perspective of where the camera was standing? But I don't know where to start. I'm new to Blender.

Comment: Look up camera mapping, this will project your texture from a camera (that you can place by hand to reproduce the perspective of this scene) onto your model.

Comment: .. and [fspy](https://fspy.io/) to construct/align your model to a matched camera, from whose view you can project the texture.